# SQL / MYSQL eject whole set if one or more match

Tags: mysql, join, mariadb

How can I eject whole table 1 id if one or more value match set ?

Following the example :

Table 1 is called "product" and table 2 is called "allergen".

Each table has many to many relationship (many product can have many allergens).

I do the following request :

```
SELECT 

p.id,
p.name,
group_concat(a.allergen_id) as allergens

FROM local_product p
LEFT  JOIN local_product_allergen a ON (a.`local_product_id` = p.id AND a.allergen_id NOT IN (1,2))

WHERE 

p.name like 'milk%'

LIMIT 0,10
```

The result returned is :

```
ID | Name     | Allergens
1  | Milk     | 3
2  | Soy Milk | 4
```

If I remove the condition "a.allergen_id NOT IN (1,2)", it returns :

```
1 | Milk      | 1,2,3
2 | Soy Milk  | 4
```

I want to eject the result "milk" @ID = 1 if one or more value match with allergens row to get that result :

```
2  | Soy Milk | 4
```

Thanks to someone who can help me, obviously it is a simplified request cause the original one is much longer and not relevant for asking help.

Nicolas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot,
it worked with one value, but not many except if value are correctly ordered.

I've found with help the correct solution : [here](https://sqltest.net/#467546)

```
SELECT
 p.id,
 p.name
FROM
 local_product p
WHERE
 p.id NOT IN ( SELECT local_product_id FROM local_product_allergen WHERE allergen_id IN (1,2) )
```

Now it works :)

Answer (score 1):

The function [find_in_set](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_find_in_set.asp) can be used to find a string in a comma delimited string.
And returns 0 if not found.

If you group, then it can be used in the HAVING clause to filter based on the result of the GROUP_CONCAT.

```
SELECT 
p.id,
p.name,
group_concat(a.allergen_id) as allergens
FROM local_product p
LEFT JOIN local_product_allergen a
  ON a.local_product_id = p.id
WHERE p.name like '%milk%'
GROUP BY p.id, p.name
HAVING find_in_set(p.id, allergens) = 0
```

A test on *rextester* [here](https://rextester.com/QSLQ55023)